# Can I use property file in maven pom.xml for flyway configuration

Tags: maven, pom.xml, flyway

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_abc</url>
        <user>db_user</user>
        <sqlMigrationPrefix>V</sqlMigrationPrefix>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't want to mention driver, url and user here. I already have a `abc.property` on `src/main/resources`. How can use that file here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Have a look at the [`properties-maven-plugin`](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/).  It allows you to read properties from a file to then use them in your pom.

Add the following plugin defintion:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>src/main/resources/abc.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

If `abc.properties` contains:

```
jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_ab
jdbc.user = db_user
```

You can then use the properties as follows:

```
<!-- language: xml -->

<driver>${jdbc.driver}</driver>
<url>${jdbc.url}</url>
<user>${jdbc.user}</user>
```

Comment: For future reference, this works great, but you need to invoke mvn initialize explicitly before calling the flay plugin e.g.

`mvn initialize flyway:migrate`

Comment: what if I have different properties files according to profiles? like for dev, abc-dev.properties, for prod abc-prod.properties

Comment: Hey where should we define the properties in pom.xml(which u mentioned it as "<!-- language: xml -->

<driver>${jdbc.driver}</driver>
<url>${jdbc.url}</url>
<user>${jdbc.user}</user>"}

Answer (score 5):

in version 3.0 you have to use configFile like :

```
<configFile>src/main/resources/db/config/flyway.properties</configFile>
```

Comment: In version 3.x .. you have configFile as -

Comment: As of v5 (and maybe even prior), the official flyway documentation has the property listed as `configFiles` (plural). See: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/#config-files

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the best and the most flexible approach is to:

a) **use profiles and filtering** - keep all configuration properties for specific profile (development, test, etc.), e.g. in development.properties:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb?useSSL=false
jdbc.user=testuser
jdbc.password=testpass
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Then, in your pom file (possibly in root pom) define a profile, e.g:

```
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>../filters/development.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </build>
        ...
```

here you can see that *development* profile is activated by default. If you want to use another profile set it with

```
-p [profile-id]
```

b) **set flyway.properties with filtered** values - your flyway.properties should sit e.g. in src/main/resources and the values should be used from the parameters defined in the profile properties file:

```
flyway.driver = ${jdbc.driver}
flyway.url = ${jdbc.url}
flyway.user = ${jdbc.user}
flyway.password = ${jdbc.password}
```

c) **reference flyway.properties from build directory** - use simple plugin configuration (I really like clean poms):

```
...
    <build>
        <resources>
            <!-- This way we instruct maven to inject values from filters into the resources -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configFile>${project.build.directory}/classes/flyway.properties</configFile>
                    <locations>
                        <location>classpath:migration/mysql</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
```

Don't forget to enable filtering in resources as shown in many examples here. My **flyway-maven-plugin version is 3.2.1** and it is managed in pluginManagement in parent pom, therefore version is not visible here. I also use explicit sql scripts with locations configuration.

Comment: If in configFile, I specify the path to src/main/resources/flyway.properties, it doesn't work even when I compile before migrating. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you try to migrate? Did you try with -X option in maven and what does it say?

Comment: It says "configFiles = []", among a lot of output

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to deal with this. One approach is to do it the other way around.

That means that the properties to use are saved as properties inside the `pom.xml` and that the file `abc.properties` only has placeholders that will be filled in at build time.

I will show you how it can be configured.

This is what the `pom.xml` will look like:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q12619446</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driver>
        <jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_abc</jdbc.url>
        <jdbc.user>db_user</jdbc.user>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <driver>${jdbc.driver}</driver>
                    <url>${jdbc.url}</url>
                    <user>${jdbc.user}</user>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this will be your `src/main/resources/abc.properties` (use the key names of your choice):

```
jdbcDriver = ${jdbc.driver}
jdbcUrl = ${jdbc.url}
jdbcUser = ${jdbc.user}
```

After the build the `target/classes/abc.properties` will look like this:

```
jdbcDriver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_abc
jdbcUser = db_user
```

---

As stated this is only **one** of several ways to do it. It might not suit your exact needs but it could.

Comment: thanks for quick reply
But the main issue is, i don't want to declare properties in POM.XML.

Answer (score 2):

Garry,

there is one more way not to place database connection parameters to your pom-file. In particular, one can add them to settings.xml file in .m2 sub-folder of the user's folder [[1]](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html). The benefit is that the db paraneters do not live in the project folder and are not transmitted to the repository, so each developer may use her own settings.

The example of the settings file could look like the example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>fw</id>
      <properties>
        <flyway.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe</flyway.url>
        <flyway.user>Your login</flyway.user>
        <flyway.password>Your password</flyway.password>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>fw</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

After that your can modify your pom-file according to the following snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>fw</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>${flyway.url}</url>
                            <user>${flyway.user}</user>
                            <password>${flyway.password}</password>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                                <version>12.1.0.1.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

In the example above Oracle's driver is used, but you can replace it with the required one.

To print current settings execute the following.

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

Comment: OK, your example works BUT what shoudl I do to load values from my application-local.yml or application-dev.yml file instead of set values in pom (hard coded)?

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.x you have configFile option

```
By default- flyway.properties in the same directory as the project POM.
```

You can add external property file in configuration section of pom  or can be pass when running maven goal example-
command line-

```
mvn <goal> -Dflyway.configFile=myConfig.properties
```

Pom file-

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
<artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
<configuration>
    <driver/>
    <url/>
    <user/>
    <password/>
    <baselineVersion>1.0</baselineVersion>
    <baselineDescription>Base Migration</baselineDescription>
    <skip>false</skip>
    <configFile>myConfig.properties</configFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```