# How Can I use Property placeholder using jpa (eclipselink)

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

Can someone suggest ,how can I replace these with value with property placeholder using eclipselink jpa

Now I am using like this

```
 <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/testapp"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    </properties>
```

I need like this mentioned below , means I need to read my property values dynamically.

```
 <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value=${jpa.jdbcurl}/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=${jpa.password}/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        </properties>
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have spring framework? if so you can use <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" /> where context mapped to "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"

Comment: I am not using spring framework.

Comment: How can I achieve this without spring framework?

Comment: Do you have maven? you can configure in maven as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619446/can-i-use-property-file-in-maven-pom-xml-for-flyway-configuration

Comment: No.I am not using maven.

Comment: How are you building your application? using ant scripts?

Comment: Yes ..Its netbeans application I created .

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in ant, may be you can try having your property file included in your build.xml as <property file="db.properties"/>