# Is there a way to read a text from a text.file and set it to maven property in pom.xml maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-antrun-plugin, maven-exec-plugin

Is there a way to read a text from a text.file and set it to maven property in pom.xml maven? I am trying with the below code. But, I will need to read the text from tmp.txt and assign it to the maven property "token".

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>generate-random-string</id>
    <phase>install</phase>
    <goals>
    <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
    <executable>bash</executable>
    <arguments>
    <argument>temp.sh</argument>
    </arguments>
    <workingDirectory>temp.txt</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

### temp.sh

```
PWD=${openssl rand hex 12}
echo $PWD >> temp.txt
```

Comment: http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/

Comment: @AndyMan - I was struggling to read a text from text file and set it to maven property.

Comment: You could try the plugin that @AndyMan suggest. Change the bash script to `PWD="$(ls -l)"
echo "token = $PWD"> temp.properties`. Then read that file and use token property. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619446/can-i-use-property-file-in-maven-pom-xml-for-flyway-configuration

Comment: I believe, it will work. Thanks.

Comment: <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId> 

reading the property from profile in this plugin will be limited or the property can be accessed throughout the file?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the properties-maven-plugin: https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/

In your pom.xml. Put the file path of the generated file on the configuration section.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <!-- your generated file -->
                <file>temp.txt</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: How would this work with text file which is just a list of values, not keys/values?

Comment: The file is a properties file. It's only key-values. For a list it should be listName=a,b,c,e... You need at least one property name to reference it